# Attempting to return MailTips using Redemption

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

[image: Screen Shot]

I'm attempting to return Mailtips(GetMailTips function) for a given Exchange user as pictured in the screen shot above. I'm stuck at the highlighted intellisense section.

Here's my code-

```
// Using redemption to return mail tips
string mailTip = "";
session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT; 
Redemption.RDOAddressEntry addressEntry = session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName("Joe Flick");
//Here I'm attempting to get the mail tips
mailTip = addressEntry.    // I would expect to see the GetMailTips Method/Fuction here but I don't see it
```

I'm attempting to translate this VB -

Added RDOAddressEntry.GetMailTips method that allows to retrieve Out-Of-Office text, max message size, etc. for an Exchange mailbox. See RDOMailTips object for more information.

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
Session.SkipAutodiscoverLookupInAD = true
set AdrEntry = Session.AddressBook.ResolveName("user@domain.demo")
set mailTips = AdrEntry.GetMailTips("me@domain.demo", "<My Password>")        optional authentication parameters for EWS
MsgBox mailTips.MaxMessageSize
```

[Detailed here](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm) -

I can't seem to get the proper syntax down as commented in the code above but can resolve the username against the GAL fine. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

![Visual Studio Screen Shot][3]

Comment: your usage of `set` looks suspicious for VB.NET...shouldn't it be `dim` (assuming the variables don't exist, and you are trying to create and initialize in the same statement)?

Comment: also - what exactly is the problem? Are you getting a syntax error? it's not entirely clear what you're asking? How to convert C# to VB? or how to use  Mailtips?

Comment: sorry, edited post to add a sceenshot

Comment: The VB is the code sample from Dmitry's site - http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm under "•    Added RDOAddressEntry.GetMailTips method " section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to return the Mailtips once I downloaded the evaluation .dll from dimastr.com. My goal here was to check to see if a conference room was restricted or not.

```
Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
Redemption.RDOAddressEntry addressEntry = session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName("User Name From the GAL");
try
{
Redemption.RDOMailTips mailtips = addressEntry.GetMailTips();
MessageBox.Show(mailtips.DeliveryRestricted.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(mailtips.CustomMailTip.ToString()); 
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RDOAddressEntry.GetMailTips was added in version 5.9 of Redemption (released  last week). What version are you using? Did you recreate the reference to Redemption in your VS project to make sure the interop dll gets regenerated?

Comment: OK, that makes sense...thanks We are running an older version